# upgrading sklearn from 0.14.1 to 0.16.1 not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need to upgrade my sklearn installation to 0.14.1 since my current version doesn't have [agglomerative clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html).

I downloaded the source for 0.16.1, extract it and within the folder I run the installation with pip this way:

```
sudo pip install .
```

Despite complaining about missing atlas as in the following extract

```
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
  Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.14.1
    Not uninstalling scikit-learn at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
  Running setup.py install for scikit-learn
    Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries  not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1521: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    blas_info:
      FOUND:
        libraries = ['blas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
        language = f77

      FOUND:
        libraries = ['blas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
        language = f77

    sklearn/setup.py:73: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
```

The installation shows a success message:

```
Successfully installed scikit-learn
Cleaning up...
```

Yet checking the scikit-learn version after installation is showing 0.14 and importing the AgglomerativeClustering is failing. Can you help?

Comment: try `--upgrade` option?

Comment: check the output of `python -c "import sklearn;print(sklearn.__version__)"`. If it does not show the latest version, your pip script and your python executable do not belong to the same interpreter.

Comment: Maybe not what you're looking for *right now*, but many people use [anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/). It gives you virtual environments and comes with many scientific packages. It would also solve your issue.

Comment: @AnandSKumar, --upgrade won't work because my initial installation was done with sudo apt-get install python-sklearn which has 0.14 as the latest version

Comment: @cel here is the output 0.14.1, does this suggest that I have multiple python installation? I double checked and this doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: @MedAli, did you install scikit-learn via `apt`? If so, use `apt-get remove` before installing a newer version with `pip`. By comparing the output of `sudo which pip` and `which python` you can find out if pip and python belong to the same interpreter.

Comment: @cel, after uninstalling scikitlearn with apt-get remove python-sklearn. I found out that sklearn 0.16 was already there. Thanks. Please formulate your answer so I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt` and `pip` are both package managers that can be used to install python packages globally. Rule of thumb: Never mix two package managers that try to install into the same directories.

In this case `pip` was smart enough not to break the installation by `apt` and therefore the old version was still present after the update. The simplest fix is to do `apt-get remove python-sklearn` first.

A better way is to strictly separate `apt` and `pip` when installing packages. I would recommend not to use `sudo pip` at all. In this scenario only `apt` is allowed to install python packages globally. Locally you can use `virtualenv` either directly or through `anaconda` to create isolated environments in which you can install the latest packages.