# can't uninstall package with pip

Tags: python, pip, linux-mint

I have installed `pillow` package, and uninstall attempt with `sudo pip uninstall pillow` leads to this message:

```
Not uninstalling Pillow at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

Manual uninstall doesn't work, because pip writes down installed packages somewhere, successfuly blocking me from installing the package again.

Comment: probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316328/upgrading-sklearn-from-0-14-1-to-0-16-1-not-working/

Comment: The clean way to solve this is to use `virtualenvs`, as I tried to outline in my answer in the linked question. By strictly separating libraries that belong to the `OS` and your personal set of libraries, you can avoid clashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This python library is important to keep Linux Mint Cinnamon running. It could be removed with `sudo apt-get remove python-pil` (not pip), but it would most likely break the operating system.

Comment: Please use the edit button beneath your question to add further information and remove this answer afterwards. At stackoverflow answers always have to provide a solution to the question.

Comment: @cel: The guy apparently figured out why he can't uninstall it. So this pretty much *is* an answer and thus belongs here and not as an edit to the question. Even though it's a bit in between... the "good" answer to his problem is using a virtualenv, but maybe he just wanted to know why he can't uninstall it (the question is somewhat vague)

Comment: @ThiefMaster, fair enough. I guess I misunderstood the last part.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the problem, as it fixed mine on Ubuntu 14.x
install `pip` (even if it is already installed), securely download `get-pip.py` from here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
Then run the following:

`sudo python get-pip.py`